# How do I get the data attribute values from an array of selected objects

Tags: javascript, dom

My HTML has a some anchor tags with a data attribute as below:

```
<a href="#" class="color" data-colorValue="FF0000">Red</a>
<a href="#" class="color" data-colorValue="0000FF">Blue</a>
<a href="#" class="color" data-colorValue="00FF00">Green</a>
```

My JavaScript code needs to add a click event listener to each anchor tag. When the event is triggered, I need to get the color value. My code is below.

```
const colors = document.querySelectorAll('.color');

for(let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
  colors[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('test to see if click is working');
    console.log(this.dataset.colorValue);
  });
}
```

I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'colorValue' of undefined"

Comment: What is `dataset`? That's what's failing. The definition is not shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.getAttribute('data-colorValue');`

```js
const colors = document.querySelectorAll('.color').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const color = el.getAttribute('data-colorValue');
    console.log(color);
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="color" data-colorValue="FF0000">Red</a>
<a href="#" class="color" data-colorValue="0000FF">Blue</a>
<a href="#" class="color" data-colorValue="00FF00">Green</a>
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. Much obliged :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you change your data attribute to `data-color-value`, you should be able to retrieve it using `this.dataset.colorValue`

See more about data attribute naming rules here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

> The name of a custom data attribute in HTML begins with data-. It must contain only letters, numbers and the following characters: dash (-), dot (.), colon (:), underscore (_) -- **but NOT any ASCII capital letters (A to Z)**.

Comment: Yes, I was able to retrieve the data attribute using the dataset.colorValue. Much obliged :-)